# passing value from powershell script to cmd script

Tags: command-line, powershell

I want to pass value “200001” from the PowerShell to cmd script “1%”
The cmd script used by multiple powershell scripts, and each PowerShell script has its own value.

PS script:

```
function CallcmdExtract
{
$var_cmd=  "D:\ cmd\Generatefile.cmd"
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    $ScriptPath = Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
try {
Invoke-Item $var_cmd 
    }
catch {
    throw("ERROR: Problem encountered, error=$_")
    }
}
CallcmdExtract
```

The cmd script that I want to pass the value to it is

```
@echo off
IF (%1) == () GOTO EXIT_ERROR
SET CLIENT=%1
.
.
.
```

Comment: You should really port your batch script to powershell instead.

Answer (score 1):

i have solved the problem using

- $Value_you_want_to_pass = XXXXXX
- Invoke-command -ScriptBlock {& $cmdpath $Value_you_want_to_pass}

Answer (score 0):

I pass with tmp files when running CMD as a separate process, instead of calling from powershell:

```
$size | Out-File -Encoding "ASCII" tmp
```

Access via CMD:

```
set /p size=<tmp
```

Saves me porting batch files to powershell scripts. Afterall, 64-bit computing potential hasn't fully been realized yet, and 16 & 32-bit computing are still here, even running on 64-bit hardware.

Note the use of ASCII encoding in the powershell code, to avoid BOM & UTF16 being passed to batch scripts.